# DataRecognitionClient returns duplicated results

Tags: speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I am using the Microsoft (Oxford) Cognitive Services Speech API client SDK.

The following is the test result after running the [sample code](https://github.com/Microsoft/ProjectOxford-ClientSDK/tree/master/Speech)
with the stock audio samples and without changing the code (as is)

```
--- OnDataShortPhraseResponseReceivedHandler ---
********* Final n-BEST Results *********
Confidence=High, Text="What's the weather like?"
Confidence=High, Text="What's the weather like?"
```

As you can see, I am getting two identical results. I wonder if you can shed some light to why that is (duplicated results)?

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to the fact that the underlying phoeneme structure might be different than the text recognition. This is not common but can happen.